# Ajax-запрос, сервер (php) возвращает null

Tags: php, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать отправку Ajax-запроса с данными из формы html. Вот файл javaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "... .php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(d) {
                ...

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

В файле ... .php след.:

```
    $data =  json_decode($_POST['data']);
    $dataJson = json_encode($data);
    echo $dataJson;
```

Ответ от сервера - Null. Не пойму, в чем причина. В JavaScript переменная data содержит объекты...

Comment: это полное содержание php файла, или есть ещё что то?

Comment: Остальной код, я закомментировал. Оставил только эти строчки

Comment: Недавно сталкивался с этой проблемой, но не помню как решил; по-моему косяк в кодировке данных (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) был.

Comment: А может и в «same origin policy» ...

Comment: Чтобы дополнять свой вопрос, используйте кнопку [edit].

Comment: Точно, только у меня не `null` возвращал, а `0`: https://jsfiddle.net/wom4ckbc/. P. S. Same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

В твоем случае свойство `data` должно быть объектом. `$_POST['data']` будет работать если: `data: {data: data}`. Ну т.е. ты должен передать объект в запрос чтобы он дошел

```
var dataD = JSON.stringify(
    {
        a: 15, 
        b: 18
    }
);

console.log('DATA=', dataD);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myFile.php",
    data: {
        data: dataD
    },
    success: function(d) {
        console.log('D=', d);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
    }
});
```